# Configure poetry in Jenkins

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, jenkins-groovy, python-poetry

I have inherited a small python project that listed its dependencies using a requirements.txt file.

I googled how to produce reproductible builds and stambled upon Poetry. I configured it, and it works great locally. I have generated a `pyproject.toml` and `poetry.lock` file which I added to git.

Now I want to do build that project in Jenkins. I want to make sure that the jenkins build uses my python version and my list of dependencies, and that each build is independant and does not contamine / get contaminated by other python configurations elsewhere on the Jenkins server (the only configuration that I think I can safely mutualize are the downloaded versioned dependencies, similar to the local maven .m2 repo for java, so that I don't download the same dependencies over and over).

This is what I tried:

```
stage('configure a local Python') {
    catchError {
        sh "rm -rf $WORKSPACE/.pyenv-python*"
    }
    withPythonEnv('python3') {
        sh "pip install --upgrade setuptools pip wheel"
        sh "curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python"
        dir ('project') {
            sh ". `$HOME/.poetry/bin/poetry env info --path`/bin/activate"
            sh "$HOME/.poetry/bin/poetry install --no-root"
        }
    }
}

stage('Build') {
    withPythonEnv('python3') {
        dir ('project') {
            sh "build..."
        }
    }
}
```

The build part fails with

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib_metadata'
```

From what I gathered it's due to a version mismatch (3.7 vs 3.8), so it means the first part must be wrong, as it works locally.

I have little experience with Python & Jenkins, so can you please help me figure out what's wrong with the configuration of my local python in Jenkins ?

Thanks

Comment: shouldn't your Jenkins admin provide you with `agents` that have poetry pre-installed?